# Burninate [i-know-the-answer] and [i-don't-know-the-answer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

We have a pair of [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) — tags that do not describe the content of the question, but instead describe some context around the question.

- [challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge): indicates that the asker wants the puzzle to be solved. At best this is a synonym of [solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solutions). At worst, this means “I know the answer”, which is purely contextual information — exactly the same question asked by someone who doesn't know the answer wouldn't have this tag.
- [solution-unknown](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-unknown): indicates that the asker doesn't know the solution. Exactly the same question asked by someone who knows the answer wouldn't have this tag.

The [solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solutions) tag is less clearly bad, but I don't like it much either: most questions here are about solutions to puzzles in one way or another, excluding the few questions that focus on creation or on mechanical puzzle manipulation.

Comment: [solution-unknown] burninated manually. Will wait for community input before acting on others.

Comment: What is your point here exactly?

Comment: @klm123 “Burninate” = destroy, specifically in the context of removing a tag from a Stack Exchange site. It's a [Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/101417#101417). I mean that since these tags are bad, they should be removed.

Comment: @Shog9 If it is 'status-completed', maybe someone should post a good answer here for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

As the creator of [solution-unknown](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-unknown), I (of course) found it useful. Perhaps it needed a better name, but I find it useful to know whether the OP has an answer in mind or not.

[As I've said before](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1322/68), I think this stack is unique, in that most questions asked here already have an answer. On other stacks, questions may be asked where the OP already has an answer, but there they're asked and self-answered to spread knowledge.

Here, those kinds of questions are asked to test the other users, the known answer withheld until later. In these cases (let's call them 'challenges') I consider the answer the OP knows but hasn't given yet, to be very much a part of the question.
So I do *not* consider two questions, one a challenge, one the solution unknown, to be the same, even though the puzzle itself may be the same word for word.

On a stack where most questions are challenges, and where users may be disappointed to find out the OP *doesn't* have a definitive answer, I find it useful to tell challenges, from puzzles *without* a known solution, from other questions *about* puzzles.

Answer (score -1):

About "solution" tag. What does this site is created for? I would think that it is created for puzzle-creation question and in perspective they are should be majority. Because all other types of questions:

1. **"Find me a solution to this puzzle?" type.** First, any puzzle can be asked on the site, which correspond to their field - mathematics, logics (philosophy), chess, physics(?). Second, there is finite number of such puzzles.
2. **"Explain me a solution to this puzzle?" type.** I do not see any differences with 1., ether you know and understand the solution to puzzle, or you don't and need someone to show you. All these can be done on specific field sites.
3. **"Find me a solution to brain-teaser?" type.** There is no site for them, but it looks like they will be forbidden here eventually.
4. **Factual type. ("When this puzzle was created?)" type.** Here is not so much questions I saw like this. Most of information about well known puzzles are already stored in wikipedia, such a question about not well known puzzles nobody will ask.

Therefore I would conclude that puzzle-creation question will be majority here (if you manage to attract experts). And there is a sense to create meta tags for each of others categories - this will help to find them among majority of questions.

How do You see it?

Comment: Yes, these types of questions are definitely on-topic, this question is just about a couple particular tags that we don't want them to be tagged with.